# How can I prevent neglect, formality and hypocrisy that emerges during Synodal Path in my parish?

Tags: catholicism, synodal-path

It is as simple as that. Formality, hypocrisy emerges during the first days and weeks of Synodal way in our parish. No word from priest. He just read  a long document about Synodal way as a sermon and without comments. No thought, no words, no attitude. Just plain neglect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pope Francis said this](https://www.americamagazine.org/faith/2020/11/25/pope-francis-laments-synodal-paths-lack-holy-spirit-239354) on Nov 25 2020 regarding synodal path:

> "At times, I feel a great sadness when I see a community that, with
> goodwill, takes a wrong path because it thinks it is making the church
> through gatherings, as if it were a political party: the majority, the
> minority, what this one thinks of this or that or the other, (saying),
> 'This is like a synod, a synodal path that we must take,'" the pope
> said Nov. 25 during his weekly general audience.
>
> "I ask myself, 'Where is the Holy Spirit there? Where is prayer? Where
> is the community's love? Where is the Eucharist?' Without these four
> coordinates, the church becomes a human society, a political party,"
> he said. "But there is no Holy Spirit."

So, in summarizing this summary of what Pope Francis said, Prayer, the Eucharist, community's love. Inviting the Holy Spirit.